# Karma dows not open chrome

Tags: angular, testing, frontend, karma-runner, jhipster

I am trying to find out how to test in Angular2 properly with Karma and Jasmine.

I´ve got the problem as follows:
- If I run my tests by "ng test" no Browser opens and shows the testresults after the run.

- If I change the value "singlerun" in my karma.conf.js to true my browser suddenly opens after the testrun, but I get the message, that Chrome is idle.

Here is my karma.conf.js

```
const webpackConfig = require('../../../webpack/webpack.test.js');

const WATCH = process.argv.includes('--watch');

module.exports = (config) => {
config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, 
exclude)
    basePath: './',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-
adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'intl-shim'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'spec/entry.ts'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-
preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        'spec/entry.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },

    webpack: webpackConfig(WATCH),

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-
reporter
    reporters: ['dots', 'junit', 'progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul', 
'notify'],

    junitReporter: {
        outputFile: '../../../../target/test-results/karma/TESTS-
results.xml'
    },

    notifyReporter: {
        reportEachFailure: true, // Default: false, will notify on 
every failed sepc
        reportSuccess: true // Default: true, will notify when a suite 
was successful
    },


    remapIstanbulReporter: {
        reports: { // eslint-disable-line
            'lcovonly': 'target/test-results/coverage/report-
lcov/lcov.info',
            'html': 'target/test-results/coverage',
            'text-summary': null
        }
    },

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || 
config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any 
file changes
    autoWatch: WATCH,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: 
https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    autowatch: true,
    // Ensure all browsers can run tests written in .ts files
    mime: {
        'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
});
```

};